# Add a save button for the beta programs

Tags: feature-request, new-nav, developer-story

Currently, in your profile settings, there are checkboxes that state what beta programs you are currently in.

If you accidentally press one of those checkboxes, the information will automatically update on the server. This means that if you click a checkbox by mistake it is automatically saved.

For the "new navigation" and the "developer story" beta programs this means that you are thrown out of the beta programs, and are placed back into the queue to join the programs later.

This happened to me with the new navigation beta feature, I always used the new navigation, but because of an accidental misclick, I can no longer access the new navigation.

### My feature request:

Add a save button for the "beta programs" so you cannot accidentally throw yourself out the programs you use.

Comment: I've been in the queue for a couple of days now so the more people who make this mistake the better for me :P (I still upvoted)

Comment: Or show a “Are you Sure?” box.

Comment: Not having this is a huge no no in UX terms as well.  You leave the user in a confused state as to whether the system really saved the changes or not.  It would be better that upon changing anything in your profile you are required to hit save.

Comment: @JonH Outside leaving the user confused, it's worse, the effects aren't reversible like a normal form in this case

Comment: @Ferrybig - Yes I understand and that is just too bad.  This is why any change needs some sort of confirmation.  In terms of UX, I've seen a lot of sites do similiar things like this and guess what - It ends up being thrown out because it was not tested on users correctly.  This is one of those things that at first glance seems so nice that it auto updates yet it bites you badly because of the effects behind not asking the user if they want their changes saved.  My proposal is to redo this entirely and do not make any db updates until a save is pressed and confirmed.

Comment: @JonH "This is one of those things that at first glance seems so nice that it auto updates" => Never seemed nice to me, even at first glace

Comment: Save buttons are crucial. +1